# Remove unknown contents of a text file in PHP

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

Is there a way to remove contents (substring) of a text file in PHP.

I know the start and the end of the string to remove, but not everything in between the content

**File (routes.php) I want to edit**

```
I want to keep this text here
# [[[@-100] I also want to remove the comment line here
  I want to remove this text here
# I also want to remove this line  [@-100]]]
I want to keep this line too
```

So I want to remove the content block that starts with   `# [[[@-100]` and ends with  `[@-100]]]`

**Im using codeignighter so I write my file like so**

```
$ROUTE_FILE ='system/routes.php'

$output = file_get_contents($ROUTE_FILE);

$output = $output->remove_substring(...);

$this->write_file($ROUTE_FILE, $output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tested](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/17a5d9703bc2048284537c5fd50dcc3a9756b32b):

```
$mystring='this is # [[[@-100] not [@-100]]] this string you want';

echo remove_substring('# [[[@-100]','[@-100]]]',$mystring);

function remove_substring($head,$foot,$string){
    $top=reset(explode($head,$string));
    $bottom=end(explode($foot,$string));
    return $top.$bottom;
}
```

output:

this is  this string you want

Here's a version that does not return errors:

[Tested](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b5b7057ebb1d2817ce5819ca86cb845ebac4260):

```
$mystring='this is # [[[@-100] not [@-100]]] this string you want';

echo remove_substring('# [[[@-100]','[@-100]]]',$mystring);

function remove_substring($head,$foot,$string){
    $top=explode($head,$string);
    $top=reset($top);
    $bottom=explode($foot,$string);
    $bottom=end($bottom);
    return $top.$bottom;
}
```

Comment: What does your question require that my function does not yet provide?

Answer (score 1):

- Activate `DOTALL` mode with `(?s)
- Escape the `[braces]` so the engine doesn't confuse them for a character chass
- Use `.*?` to match everything between the delimiters.

In php code:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~(?s)# \[\[\[@-100\] Start of custom routes.*?# End of custom routes \[@-100\]\]\]~',
                         '', $yourinput);
```

See the output at the bottom of [this demo](http://ideone.com/1Lk3g7).

Comment: ok thanks, I only wante the start with to be the # [[[@-100]   and end with [@-100]]] - Would I just remove the string portion from your exxample ?

Comment: Not understanding. Are you saying that you only want to remove the portion in the middle, and leave the ` # [[[@-100]` in place? Or remove the whole thing. I removed the whole thing, but it's easy to tweak. Let me know.

Comment: No also want to remove the #[[[@-100] comment and everything inside it

Comment: Essentially, there is a shared routes file, my program must only access and change the code it inserts dynamically

Comment: See the output at the bottom of [this demo](http://ideone.com/1Lk3g7), then explain to me what you need to tweak so I can understand your needs.

Comment: Yes. Explain to me how the demo differs from your needs!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56046/discussion-between-zx81-and-ienumerable).

Comment: This answer does exactly like mine, once you narrow the search keys. I [tested](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc9c7dc255b8fe925e24c3c6cea6078c3b570289) it. I did not benchmark, but I'd bet it's faster than mine.